# How can I find a language from a given PDA

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I have the following PDA:
[image]

And a given solution for his languages ${L}_{\mathrm{End}}(M_2)$ and ${L}_{\mathrm{PDA}}(M_2)$ with $ \mathrm{L}_{\mathrm{End}}\left(\mathrm{M}_{2}\right)=\left\{\mathrm{a}^{\mathrm{n}} \mathrm{b}^{\mathrm{m}} x\mid \mathrm{n}, \mathrm{m} \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \wedge x \in\{\mathrm{b}, \mathrm{c}\}^{*} \wedge| x |=\mathrm{m}\right\} $

and

$ \mathrm{L}_{\mathrm{PDA}} = \{a^*\} $

My problem is that I do not understand how to come up with this solution.
If I had a DFA, it would not be a problem to find the language, but here i have to find two, and I have no idea how find them.

Comment: The same principle applies: guess and prove. In addition to how you approach DFAs, you want to look for matching stack operations: when are the same symbols pushed to and later popped off the stack? What's the pattern?

Comment: The general procedures are described here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755.